# Comments Moderation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

I've successfully added a comment box as described at the social plugins page:

I also included the following metatags:

```
<meta content='XXX' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='YYY' property='fb:admins'/>
<meta content="YYY" property="fb:moderator"/>
```

Nothing seems to make a difference!

EDIT: yes, the values are ok, I had the older version and everything used to work.

Thanks!

Comment: So those users in `fb:moderator` do or do not have moderator permissions? Please explain your question little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just broken in IE? If so, maybe you forgot to add the fb namespace to your html tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```